# Shift Register Vs Multiplexer

Tags: hardware, vhdl, verilog, fpga

I am not sure about an implementation. I've a multiplexer 8 input, 1 output and 3 select signal. One of these selects signal sequentialy acquires all value of a bit vector. Now I can choose 2 way.

The first way is to use another multiplexer where the input is the bit vector and the select signal is a counter log2 of the input.

The second way is to use a shift register and take the LSB bit of the vector.

What is the best solution in terms of area in a FPGA ?

Comment: I think you'll get better answers here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I thought it was ok to post here. I've seen that there are the tag so I thought it was ok. Thanks for help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted on EE. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144254/shift-register-vs-multiplexer

Comment: @haster8558 HDL (Verilog/VHDL) questions are welcome here, but this question relates directly area on an FPGA, to me that is not programming it is hardware design. As soon as the question starts to involve design running on an FPGA, or synthesis area I consider it a hardware question more suited to [Electronics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/). There is a bit of a clamp down on cross posting especially if not declared in the question.

Comment: @Morgan: The distinction between SO and Electronics SE is apparently pretty blurry here.  C source algorithms compiles to machine code instructions, as the native resource of CPUs, and I would expect that most agree that discussion about efficient C algorithms belong at SO.  VHDL source algorithms compiles to gates, as the native resource of FPGAs, so by that analogy VHDL algorithm efficiency discussions should also belong at SO.

Comment: @MortenZilmer, I agree the line is pretty blurry. Which in-part is while I am not too keen on the crack down on cross-posting. I think it should be allowed if disclosed in the question. I personally would be happy to keep more questions on SO, but find the line gets even blurrier the further down FPGA/ASIC path you travel. These are my opinions and not to be taken as general consensus but I think it helps new users to gain some perspective on where to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets (for a incorrect start) assume that the FPGA only provides plain logical elements and flip-flops, and that the bit vector is N bits and holds the value while the used bit is selected, then the resources used by the two solutions are:

- Shift solution:

  - N flip-flops for the shifting
  - N 2-1 muxes for flip-flop loading
- Mux solution:

  - (N - 1) 2-1 muxes for the larger N-1 mux
  - log2(N) flip-flops for the counter

So this weights towards the mux solution, since the both needs almost the same number of 2-1 muxes due to the required initial loading of the N bit shift register, but the mux solution requires less flip-flops.

However, FPGAs depends heavily on LUTs which are usually based on small memory, and an additional feature is that these small memories can often be used as shift registers also.  FPGAs with this feature allows LUT memory to be written directly, and then shifted, and this can be done without any 2-1 muxes for loading.  So in this case the resources used for the shift solution are:

- Shift solution with LUT for shifting:

  - ? LUT for the loading and shifting

So the conclusion is that the best way to determine and achieve an optimal solution for an FPGA, is to know and utilize the feature of the specific target FPGA, and then try the implementing to be sure the synthesis tool maps the design correctly.

Comment: For either solution you need storage to store the value your iterating over. You haven't included this in the mux-solution, and it **is** the shift-register. So I'd say the mux solution will always lose.

Comment: @PaulS: I made the explicit assumption in the first paragraph that "... the bit vector ... holds the value while the used bit is selected ...", thus no storage for the bit vector in the mux solution.  If the FPGA has shift capability in the LUTs, then use these is always to prefer.

Comment: You're right, I did miss that statement. Still, I think it's worth stating that often you'd get the storage for the shift register for free, just because you already needed a register there (e.g. for timing, or so that the driving logic can start the next calculation).